# Send a single signal from Python to Arduino for a range of values

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port

Python Code:

```
ser = serial.Serial("COM1", 19200, timeout=5)
time.sleep(2)
while True:
    # ... img processing
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    detected = False


    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        # ... faces processing
        detect_face=x


        print 'face distance: ', detect_face
        if 80 < detect_face < 100:
            if detected:
               pass
            else:
               print '1'
               detected = True
        else:
            if detected:
               print '2'
               detected = False
            else:
               pass
```

`detect_face` value:

```
face distance:  123
face distance:  112
face distance:  99
1
face distance:  95
1
face distance:  64
face distance:  68
face distance:  73
face distance:  80
face distance:  80
face distance:  88
1
face distance:  88
1
face distance:  88
1
face distance:  97
1
face distance:  102
face distance:  112
```

Arduino code:

```
void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) { 
    incomingBit = Serial.read();
    switch (incomingBit) {
      case '1':
          Servo1.write(0); 
          delay(1000); 

          Servo1.write(90); 
          delay(1000); 

          Servo1.write(180); 
          delay(1000); 
          //exit(0);
       break;

       case '2' :
         Servo1.write(0);
       break;
```

Now what I want to do is to send a 'single' signal '1', each time `80 < 
 detect_face < 100`. For example, when `detect_face` is `104,95,80,80,98,100,...` `ser.write('1')` is sending signal 4 times as a result my servo connected to Arduino is moving 4 times in a loop. What i want is for `detect_face` values `104,95,80,80,98,100` send a signal to arduino only one time not 4 times. How can I do that on the Python side? or even at Arduino side?

Comment: Hi, try to focus your question a bit more next time: [mcve].

Comment: Note that the code has been updated and does not reflect the original problem anymore (@sayem48 this is going to confuse future readers...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a snippet that is easy to play with:

```
for detect_face in [79,80,81, 90, 99,100,101]:
    print(detect_face)
    if 80 < detect_face < 100:
        print(' 1')
    else:
        print(' 2')
```

It prints

```
79
 2
80
 2
81
 1
90
 1
99
 1
100
 2
101
 2
```

so that condition seems to work as you want.

If I understand you correctly, your question is how to prevent this from running several times in a row, so that `[90,90,90,110,110,110,90,90,90]` does not result in

```
90
 1
90
 1
90
 1
110
 2
110
 2
110
 2
90
 1
90
 1
90
 1
```

but in this instead:

```
90
 1
90
90
110
 2
110
110
90
 1
90
90
```

So the code also has to detect a change in the state, not just a threshold. Keeping and comparing the state makes it an edge detector (state-change):

```
detected = False

for detect_face in [90,90,90,110,110,110,90,90,90]:
    print(detect_face)
    if 80 < detect_face < 100:
        if detected:
            pass
        else:
            print(' 1')
            detected = True
    else:
        if detected:
            print(' 2')
            detected = False
        else:
            pass
```

(See its output above)

Note the symmetry of the conditions. In electronics, this is a [flip-flop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)).

This is equivalend to keeping the last result and comparing that with the current one; if they differ, it's an edge (event).

The threshold could be extended with *hysteresis*.

Comment: You are spot on! But still having a bit of trouble.

Comment: I have edited my code using your suggestion and also posted updated results. Still getting the same output.  Probably using loop wrongly?

Comment: Print faces to see the problem.

Comment: Here is the values of faces: `faces [[294 166 174 174]]
face distance:  294
faces [[294 168 168 168]]
face distance:  294
faces [[294 170 171 171]]
face distance:  294
faces [[297 169 169 169]]
face distance:  297
faces [[296 168 167 167]]
face distance:  296`

Comment: I can't figure out the problem. @handle

Comment: I know what the problem is, I wanted you to figure it out. Simulate the program in your head...

Comment: Ok whatever. Move `detected` out of your loop to keep the state - you're resetting it in every iteration.

Comment: It worked. thanks for the great help. But now having another problem with object tracking. here is the new post :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44035872/detected-object-does-not-pass-through-camera-view-in-opencv-python                                             Have a look when you are free.